# How can I move through all the records in MySQL update query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a java code where I need to read many lines from a text file and I need to update records with the read lines. For example, the text file contains: aaa, bbb, ccc, .. etc (the comma means new line), so, I want to update col4 in record1 with the value aaa, record2 with the value bbb, etc.

How can I make update statement that makes the update for every record automatically ??

This is my Java code:

```
counter=0;
        while((fileLine=in.readLine())!=null) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Line read is: "+fileLine);

                //execute db insertion
                try {
                    //insert in the database
                    String Query= "update db.table set col4=?";    //database
                    preparedStmt3 = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query); 
                    preparedStmt3.setString (1, fileLine);
                    preparedStmt3.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Complete update statement for row: "+counter);
                    counter++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("DB_Error:_"+ e.toString());
                }

        } //end while loop
```

Comment: Is there another column in the table (the primary key maybe) that represents the line number? With your current query, you're updating the entire table, not a single line.

Comment: Your code updates the column of all rows, not only one specific record. You need to add a where clause to your update statement by which you can select the correct row. Is there some criteria by which you can connect the rows in your file with the records in the DB?

Comment: Yes. Assume there is a primary key which is a unique number auto increment (assume 1,2,3, etc). Can you write me the query that can move through these numbers for the whole table ?

Comment: "update db.table set col4 = ? where id = ?" and preparedStmt3.setInt(2, counter)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** As `Andreas` and `Frank` noted, your update statement looks a little incorrect. You seem to be missing a *where* clause from your update statement. This is because, you're trying to set only one parameter to your PreparedStatement. Ideally an update statement looks something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=?, column2=?,...
WHERE some_column=?
```

i.e. you at least need to have one or more columns in your *where* clause to identify which record or records that needs be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated (*which is something that you might not want to do*)

Also, as a performance improvement for huge data set, consider updating in batch. So here's what you would do:

- Create a batch size.
- For each line that you read from your file, add it to batch. This you can do by calling the [addBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) method of *PreparedStatement*
- Once you reach the batch size, execute the batch by calling [executeBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29). You would then clear you batch ([clearBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#clearBatch%28%29))and continue the process till you're done with reading all the lines from your file.

Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt3 = null;
try{
    counter=0;
    int batchCutoff = 1000, currentBatchSize = 0;

    Query= "update db.table set col4=?";    //database
    preparedStmt3 = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query); 

    while((fileLine=in.readLine())!=null) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Line read is: "+fileLine);
        //execute db insertion
        try {
            //insert in the database
            preparedStmt3.setString (1, fileLine);
            preparedStmt3.addBatch();
            preparedStmt3.clearParameters();
            currentBatchSize++;

            if(currentBatchSize >= batchCutoff){
                preparedStmt3.executeBatch();
                preparedStmt3.clearBatch();
                System.out.println("Complete update statement for: "+currentBatchSize+" row(s)");
                currentBatchSize = 0;
            }
            counter++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("DB_Error:_"+ e.toString());
        }
    } //end while loop 
    //In case the cut-off has not been reached and some statements in the batch are remaining
    try{
        preparedStmt3.executeBatch();
        preparedStmt3.clearBatch();
    }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("DB_Error:_"+ e.toString());
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Total of: "+counter+" row(s) updated");
    }
}finally{
    if(preparedStmt3 != null){
        try{
            preparedStmt3.close();
        }catch(Exception exe){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue is the update statement itself: it updates all rows. He needs to think about some where clause to define which row to update...

Comment: @Sujay: I have no idea how to do this. Can you please provide me with the exact code needed ?

Comment: As noted by @Frank and myself, your first need to fix your update statement. Your code should work very well,even without batching. Once it works, you can think about adding batching (which is primarily a performance enhancement)

Comment: @JuryA Batching's definitely not the problem, though you'll want to move the creation of the PreparedStatement out of the loop, set auto-commit off and commit the transaction at the end of the loop. But first, fix the query's logic.

Comment: @Andreas: I understand the idea but don't know how to write this query. Assume the pk_id is my primary key. My query should be: `Query= "update test.pk set pk_hex=? where pk_id= ";` How can I specify the pk_id value to move through the whole table??

Comment: @JuryA - where do you get the `pk_id` from?

Comment: It is an auto increment number.

Comment: The question is: how do you connect the lines of your file with the rows of your table? Think about which line in the file corresponds to which record and how can you select it! For example, you could have one column in your table which contains the line number from your file, so that you can use this in your where clause. But it really depends on what you want to achieve ...

Comment: It is almost not possible to connect. The connection is the order. Lin1 is record1, line2 is record2, etc.

Comment: That I expected ;) That is not how relational databases usually work - there is no such thing as "record 1", "record 2", even though in reality it can be that if you select all records you get them in the same order you inserted them, it is not guarantied. There might be a RowId column which is provided by the DB - which DB system are you using?

Comment: Then there must be a column in your DB that reflects that order: id or whatever.  Join on it and a inputLineNo++ in your Java code. Otherwise, mission impossible. Note: you can't easily match an autoincrement field against that order if there was any deletion in the DB. It's possible with some rather complex tricks, but it's better to fix the schema.

Comment: @Sujay you're leaking PreparedStatements in the loop (as in Jury A's code), so the batch won't work. You should fix your example.

Comment: @FrankPavageau: Thanks for the heads-up! Fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a counter you can use it in where clause

```
----->>counter=1;
    while((fileLine=in.readLine())!=null) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Line read is: "+fileLine);

            //execute db insertion
            try {
                //insert in the database
                String Query= "update db.table set col4=? where id=?";    //database
                preparedStmt3 = DBConnection.con.prepareStatement(Query); 
                preparedStmt3.setString (1, fileLine);
       ---->>   preparedStmt3.setInt(2,counter);
                preparedStmt3.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Complete update statement for row: "+counter);
                counter++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("DB_Error:_"+ e.toString());
            }

    } //end while loop
```

I have inserted the arrow where I have made changes